# javassist copy a method with annotation

Tags: java, annotations, decompiling

This is the original method:

```
  @GET
  @Produces({"application/json"})
  public Response getTermClouds(@Context SecurityContext secCtxt, @Context UriInfo ui)
  {
    return null
  }
```

I want to copy this method but add a new String parameter,and the annotations of the new method is the same as before,like this:

```
  @GET
  @Produces({"application/json"})
  public Response getTermClouds(@Context SecurityContext secCtxt, @Context UriInfo ui,String newParam)
  {
    return null
  }
```

I use javassist to do it,i don`t want to add a "get" annotation and then add a "produces" annotation,because there may be many other annotations which are unkown.How to do it as a common way?

Answer (score 1):

When You try adding a new parameter to a method , Javassist does not allow to add an extra parameter to an existing method,Instead of doing that, a new method receiving the extra parameter as well as the other parameters is added to the same class.

A copy of the the CtMethod object can be obtained by CtNewMethod.copy().

Try [this](https://jboss-javassist.github.io/javassist/tutorial/tutorial2.html) to create a copy of Your previous method. And can you explain exactly what you want to be done with annotations?

Comment: Actually,it is a jax-rs class with an annotation named "Path".I dont have the source code,i want to add a parameter "@context  HttpSevletRequest request" to the method.so I can get real path from it. Though I can copy a new method but it has no annotation.Or parse a new method from a string,also no annotaion,and no generic type.

Comment: @user6630815 you can add annotations to a method at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

I realize this is old now, but I ran into the same problem trying to add parameters to Spring web handler methods, and I've figured it out. You need to copy the attributes of the old class to the new one. You'll also likely want to remove them from the old one to prevent possible conflicts. The code looks like this:

```
//Create a new method with the same name as the old one
CtMethod mNew = CtNewMethod.copy(mOrig, curClass, null);

//Copy all attributes from the old method to the new one. This includes annotations
for(Object attribute: mOrig.getMethodInfo().getAttributes()) {
    m.getMethodInfo().addAttribute((AttributeInfo)attribute);
}

//Remove the method and parameter annotations from the old method
mOrig.getMethodInfo().removeAttribute(AnnotationsAttribute.visibleTag);
mOrig.getMethodInfo().removeAttribute(ParameterAnnotationsAttribute.visibleTag);

//Add the new String parameter to the new method
m.addParameter(cp.getOrNull("java.lang.String"));

//Add a new empty annotation entry for the new parameter (not sure this part is necessary for you. 
//In my case, I was adding a new parameter to the beginning, so the old ones needed to be offset.
ParameterAnnotationsAttribute paa = (ParameterAnnotationsAttribute)m.getMethodInfo().getAttribute(ParameterAnnotationsAttribute.visibleTag);
Annotation[][] oldAnnos = paa.getAnnotations();
Annotation[][] newAnnos = new Annotation[oldAnnos.length + 1][];
newAnnos[oldAnnos.length] = new Annotation[] {};
System.arraycopy(oldAnnos, 0, newAnnos, 0, oldAnnos.length);
paa.setAnnotations(newAnnos);

//Rename the old method and add the new one to the class
mOrig.setName(mOrig.getName() + "_replaced");
curClass.addMethod(m);
```